# Schedule cron every 3 hour in chef recipe

Tags: linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe

How do I schedule cron job to run every 3 hours ?
 This is my code :

```
cron_d 'hdfs_space.sh' do
  minute '59'
  command '/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs_space.sh'
  user 'hdfs'
  only_if {File.exists?('/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs_space.sh')}
end
```

is it hour '*/3' ?

Thanks

Comment: From the chef doco I just glanced over it's not quite clear whether or not it permits this syntax, but yes, if this were a plain linux crontab the "*/3" notation is indeed correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Chef cron resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html) has an `hour` attribute. Your `cron` declaration should be something like:

```
cron 'hdfs_space.sh' do
  hour '*/3'
  command '/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs_space.sh'
  user 'hdfs'
  only_if {File.exists?('/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs_space.sh')}
end
```

Comment: The default value for `minute` is `*` and so this will every 4 hours, but will run every minute of that hour.

Answer (score 5):

To schedule cron for every 3 hour in chef recipe use the hour and minute attributes of cron.

```
cron 'hdfs_space.sh' do
    minute '0'
    hour '*/3'
    command '/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs_space.sh'
    user 'hdfs'
    only_if {File.exists?('/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs_space.sh')}
end
```

If we dont specify the minute option the cron will execute every minute of every 3rd hour. So along with the hour attribute use the minute attribute and set it to '0' .

Comment: why is hour '*/3' and not just 3?

Comment: @red888 If you use just "3" The cron will run only at 3 and not at an interval of every three hours.  I wanted my cron to run at an interval of every 3 hours.